# Outlook VBA loading a saved file from HD

Tags: vba, outlook

I've found quite a bit on how to automate saving emails and attachments from Outlook to drive locations, but I'm lost on how to access and manipulate those objects that are now saved. So, as an example, I have a folder on my desktop ('C:\Desktop\emails\') with about 1000 emails, and I need to pull the attachments from each of them. The process of extracting attachments in an iterated method is well documented, I'm just stuck on how to actually specify that folder and use it.

Comment: You can use Dir() to loop through items in a folder.  As for saving attachments, see here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b7bb25a6-42ac-4c5c-bccb-ed108fd22412/open-msg-file-and-save-attachment-with-vba

Answer (score 0):

Are the MSG files? Use Application.Session.OpenSharedItem to open each MSG file and get back the MailItem object.